# how is the output coming as 1 and not the address of j

Tags: c, scanf

why is the output  coming as 1 and not the address of j i tried with every alphabets still it's giving 1 as output

how is this program not giving address of j and why is it giving 1 as output i tried with every letters as input still it's giving 1?

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    char arr[100];
    printf("%d", scanf("%s", arr));
    /* Suppose that input value given
         for above scanf is "jje" */
    return 2;
}
```

shouldn't it give the address of 1st letter ie j

Comment: Check a reference for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) : its return value is the number of arguments assigned (ie. just 1 in your case assuming a successful read).

Comment: *NEVER* print what you think to be addresses with `%d`. `%p` is better (at least for real pointers).

Answer (score 2):

No. You're printing the return value of [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). This isn't any address, but (emphasis mine):

> On success, **the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled**. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Since that `scanf` result successfully matches the `%d`, you get `1`.

If you wanted to print that address, which is the address of `arr`, you could try

```
printf("%p", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are printing the return value of `scanf()` which is the number of successful matches scanf makes which in your case is 1 as you're capturing a single string value.